# Adding date on right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, datetime, date

I want a result like this, a simple date on the right.
Sorry for the question, I'm a beginner
[image]

Comment: `\par\hfill\textsl{27/02/2018}\par` --- but you really should give more details. Do you want it mid-paragraph or between paragraphs (my snippet will force a paragraph). Just a date typed in or some kind of automatic one? It should prevent a pagebreak before/after?

Comment: @Rmano Both between paragraphs and in the middle, as in the example
The date must not be automatic but entered manually

Answer (score 2):

In this situation you can use `\vadjust` to let TeX insert something after whichever line the `\vadjust` was used in. Additionally, I use `\@bpshack` and `\@esphack` (space hack of the LaTeX kernel) that suppresses additional spaces caused by the macro when used inside the line.

Moreover I used the starred form of `\newcommand` (so the argument cannot contain an explicit `\par` token, something which would be wrong for this usage -- and break inside an internal of `\textsc` anyway).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\providecommand\bigstrut{\vrule width 0pt height 3ex depth 2ex\relax}
\newcommand*\slapR[1]{\par\hfill\textsl{\bigstrut #1}\par}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\slapRmiddle[1]
  {\@bsphack\vadjust{\null\hfill\textsl{\bigstrut #1}\par}\@esphack}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Previous paragraph ends here.

\slapR{2021/07/06}

It is not trivial to add the date-line in the middle of a paragraph\dots
although you can mimic it by choosing the right point where to put the
command \slapRmiddle{And then ducks arrived.} manually by trials.
Clearly, a bit of vertical space makes things a bit better-looking.
\end{document}
```

No guessing of position, hyphenation still works, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Doing that between paragraphs is easy. Inside paragraphs it's much more complicated, so the solution below relies on manually choosing where to put the command to have a good-looking line (it really creates another paragraph). Still, you can have a page break immediately after the command... but this is for another question!

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\bigstrut}{\vrule width 0pt height 3ex depth 2ex\relax}
\newcommand{\slapR}[1]{\par\hfill\textsl{\bigstrut #1}\par}
\newcommand{\slapRmiddle}[1]{{\parfillskip=0pt\par}%
    \hfill\textsl{\bigstrut #1}\par\noindent\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
Previous paragraph ends here.

\slapR{2021/07/06}

It is not trivial to add the date-line in the middle of a paragraph\dots
although you can mimic it by choosing the right point where to put the
command \slapRmiddle{And then ducks arrived.} manually by trials.
Clearly, a bit of vertical space makes things a bit better-looking.
\end{document}
```

[image]

...and as you can see, the line above the insert is quite badly spaced, so my advice is to not put dates mid-paragraph.